# Can 1 query change the same field of 2 entries in a table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that shows some images and other data from a mysql table. Using radio buttons the 'galley' field for the selected image gets changed to 3. I have this working ok, however there should only ever be one value of 3 in the table. How could i change the code below to also change any 3 already in the table to a 1 value?

```
// if featured is checked, then set gallery field to 3
if(isset($_POST['featured'])){
    $chk = (array) $_POST['featured'];
    $p = implode(',',array_keys($chk)); 
    $t = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM gallery WHERE id IN ($p)");
    if ($t){
        $q = mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE gallery SET gallery=3 WHERE id IN ($p)");
        header('Location: galleryadmin.php'); exit();
    }
    else{
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Dog Has Not Been Featured, Try Again 
                                                    Or Contact Site Developer") </script>';
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UDPATE yourtable
SET gallery = IF(id = $p, 3, 1)
```

for records where id = $p, the `if` returns `3`. For any other record, it returns `1`, and those `1`/`3` values get assigned to the gallery field.

This is somewhat inefficient, if you're on a very large table, where it'd be re-writing all but one record to basically have the same value the record had before. Performance-wise, you might be better off using a transaction and two queries:

```
start transaction;
update yourtable set gallery=1 where gallery=3;
update yourtable set gallery=3 where id=$p;
commit;
```

which should theoretically only change two records: the "old" gallery-3, and the new one that's becoming gallery-3.

Comment: Thank you @Marc B, i used the second example as some of the records have the value 2 in the gallery field. This worked a treat!